# Openlayers nomenclature grid

Tags: coordinates, openlayers

Who can help! Need to display the coordinates in the middle of the cell of grid. I do this grid, but can not to display coordinates. At zoom this coordinates must change and display on the grid (example write on leaflet).
My grid.
`https://jsfiddle.net/andrii555/setmtbsq/`
This example is written on leaflet. `http://nakarte.tk/#m=7/48.84664/26.58142&l=O/Ng`
Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need that coordinates display on the grid as in the last example. I do this grid but I can not display the coordinates.